# set focus to rich:editor in a rich:modalPanel when the modal panel popup

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a very simple popup window with a rich editor:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="commentFormPanel" width="640" height="480">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:panelGroup>Comment</h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <h:form id="commentForm">
        <rich:editor id="commentContent" width="620" height="440"
            theme="simple" viewMode="visual"
            value="#{commentHome.content}" />
    </h:form>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Is it possible to set focus in the rich:editor when the modal panel pops up?

Someone suggested to use this:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'commentForm:commentContent');
```

I tried but it did not work. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks.

Update:

I tried a few things:

a).

```
<rich:editor id="commentContent" width="620" height="440"
    theme="simple" viewMode="visual">
    <f:param name="auto_focus" value="commentForm:commentContent" />
</rich:editor>
```

b).

```
<rich:modalPanel onshow="tinyMCE.get('commentForm:commentContent').focus();">
```

both did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
        <rich:editor id="commentContent" width="620" height="440"
            theme="simple" viewMode="visual" useSeamText="false"
            value="#{commentHome.content}"
            oninit="setTimeout( function() { tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'commentForm:commentContentTextArea'); }, 1);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<rich:jQuery query="focus().select()" selector="#commentContent" name="focusInput"/>

<script>
  focusInput();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Ramin, I tried you code but did not work for rich:editor. If I use a h:inputTextarea or h:inputText, your code works well.

Answer (score 0):

Add Tag domElementAttachment="parent" to rich:modalPanel